# One-to-Many Parent Child relationship: group by child column, aggregate parent column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose you have the following two tables for logging purchases:

```
create table shopping_cart (
    id int,
    total float,
    purchase_date datetime
)

create table product_purchase (
    id int,
    shopping_cart int,
    product varchar(100)
)
```

for each row in cart_purchases you'll get multiple rows in product_purchases. How can you construct a query to answer the question: for each product what was the average cart total? The obvious thing doesn't work:

```
select pp.product, avg(cart.total) from shopping_cart cart 
inner join product_purchase pp on cart.id = pp.shopping_cart
group by pp.product
```

because the parent rows will be multiplied by the child rows, throwing off the average. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this at the query level.  I think you need to put **product** in your shopping cart - i.e. change your data model.

Comment: Maybe use a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wanted an average of product cost/per cart in which case you can use something like this

```
SELECT p2.product,avg(avg_product_cost) as avg
 FROM
   (SELECT s.id,s.total/count(p.id) as avg_product_cost
    FROM shopping_cart s INNER JOIN product_purchase p ON (p.shopping_cart = s.id)
    GROUP BY s.id,s.total
   )t1
INNER JOIN
product_purchase p2 ON (p2.shopping_cart = t1.id)
GROUP BY p2.product
```

Comment: Sorry meant to include the group by in my non-working query. Group by doesn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: can you sqlfiddle.com your data? I don't know what you mean by parent rows and child rows. and maybe what your expected output from the data.

Comment: do you need to divide by the count of product in each cart?

Comment: I updated my answer to show average product cost/per cart. see if that's what you want.